# How to workaround IronPython Compile() Issue?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm trying to run the following in my C#/IronPython:

```
import re
Message = re.sub(r"^EVN\|A\d+", "EVN|A08", Message, flags=MULTILINE)
```

This works fine on real python at the command prompt.  However, once I put it into IronPython I get an error:

```
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InvokeUnaryOperator(CodeContext context, UnaryOperators oper, Object target, String errorMsg)    
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.Length(Object o)    
at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.len(Object o)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)    
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)    
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)    
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)    
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)    
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.Execute(String expression, ScriptScope scope)
```

Research led me to understand (right or wrong?) that the MULTILINE flag triggers Compile() in IronPython.  Then I found this article about its lack of support in IronPython:  https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/22692.

Removing `flags=MULTILINE` fixes the error.  However, It doesn't match on `"^EVN"` any longer.

EDIT: If I use `flags=re.MULTILINE` I receive this error:

```
ERROR Error while processing the message. Message: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'. Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'
```

END EDIT

My question is:  How can I work around this issue and still get the same results I would get at the command line given the above code snippet, but in IronPython?

I rarely use Python, let alone IronPython, so please be forgiving as I'm not sure of my alternatives.

Comment: One thing you could do is replace newlines with some other character before applying the regular expression, so you no longer need the multi-line support.

Comment: With that import of `re`, it should be `re.MULTILINE`, not just `MULTILINE`. Is there a reason why you need to do this in IronPython if you’re calling it from C#, or is that not all of your Python code?

Comment: @poke re.MULTILINE did not help.  It is erroring on the "flags" saying the above error (I edited the comment with it just now)

Comment: It’s possible that IronPython doesn’t support flags that way. You can try compiling your expression first: `regex = re.compile('^EVN\|A\d+', re.MULTILINE)` and then do `Message = regex.sub('EVN|A08', Message)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible that IronPython does not support the `flags` keyword argument in [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). To work around that issue, you can compile your regular expression first. This is recommended anyway if you plan to use your expression multiple times; and the module-level functions do it anyway.

To do that, use [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile). The flags can be passed as the second argument:

```
regex = re.compile('^EVN\|A\d+', re.MULTILINE)
```

This gives you a regular expression object, and you can directly use its [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub) method to perform your replacement:

```
Message = regex.sub('EVN|A08', Message)
```